# How can I use phone-to-phone call feature using sinch sdk?

Tags: java, phone-call, sinch

I have been trying to use sinch sdk for phone to phone calling. App to app and app to phone works but I can't create the idea that connects the app to sim so that I can call from phone to phone.

Answer (score 0):

For phone to phone it is something you would implement on your backend.

[image]

https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest#phonetophonecallingoverview you can also check out this tutorial 
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/keep-users-phone-numbers-private-uber-x/

You dont need the sdk if you want to do phone to phone, in fact i would recommend against it since it adds quite alot of code that will be unused.

Comment: do you have any chat group on stack overflow